# Issue with C programming language FOR loop

Tags: c, linked-list

I have over 20 years experience in software development, but I encountered a very unusual bug in a simple C program I am going to use in a blog post aimed at junior or beginner developers.

My C program builds a linked list that is based on a struct with one integer number, and tries to build a linked list of 100,000 nodes. It uses an insert function and a FOR loop calls the insert function, this program works fine when the for loop iterates 10,000 times, but the program generates no output whatsoever when trying to iterate 100,000 times, how bizarre!

I encounter the same identical issue when running this program in Visual Studio on Windows 10, and also when compiling with gcc and running on OpenBSD Unix.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// struct type for linked list
struct Integers
{
    unsigned int nIntNumber;
    struct Integers* next;
    struct Integers* previous;
};

// head and last nodes
struct Integers* head = NULL;
struct Integers* last = NULL;

// to keep track of the current node pointed to 
struct Integers* current = NULL;

// Create Linked List
void insert(int data) {

    // Allocate memory for new node
    struct Integers* node = (struct Integers*) malloc(sizeof(struct Integers));

    node->nIntNumber = data;
    node->previous = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;

    // If head is empty, create new list
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = node;
        return;
    }

    current = head;

    // move to the end of the list
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;

    // Insert link at the end of the list
    current->next = node;
    last = node;
    node->previous = current;
}

// output the list
void outputList() {

    // start at first node in list
    struct Integers* ptr = head;

    // output the contents of the list
    while (ptr->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", ptr->nIntNumber);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // loop through total number of elements adding each integer with each iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        insert(i);
    }

   // output the contents of the list
   outputList();

  // debug
  unsigned int testInt = 0;
  printf("Max Int: %u", --testInt);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` and **do not cast** the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` and use `UINT_MAX`

Comment: In the `outputList()` function `while (ptr->next != NULL) {}` ---> `while (ptr != NULL) { }` as earlier one causes to iterate one lesser time & doesn't print last node info.

Comment: You never check the result of the allocation.

Comment: OK, it looks like the program is running, but for some reason its taking like 2 or 3 minutes to build the linked list, that is very bizarre, C programs are usually lightning fast, especially on today's modern computers with fast CPUs.

Comment: Because each time you `insert` you traverse the *whole* list. Your time complexity is quadratic. You have your `last` pointer. Use it.

Comment: In each insertion, you traverse the list to the end (instead of using `last` to find it). For node `i`, this takes `i-1` iterations. For 100,000 nodes, it takes 0+1+2+…99999 = 4,999,950,000 iterations.

Comment: To avoid what @EricPostpischil pointed, use `last` in such a way that it holds the address of last node inserted & don't traverse till last node every time as `current->next != NULL`.

Comment: Ok, OH WOW! I got this is an example off the web, and completely missed it was doing an exponential quadratic, so per your suggestion, I changed it to using LAST and that fixed the problem, thank you Eugence Sh., Eric, and Achal for pointing this issue out :-)

Comment: I hope you're planning on posting this as an example of what NOT to do.  This seems to be a textbook example of badly designed code (poor encapsulation, poor algorithm choices, code that does not do what it at first appears to do, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `last` do not iterate every time to find the last node. Loops were also incorrect

```
void insert(int data) {

    // Allocate memory for new node
    struct Integers* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if(!node) return;
    node->nIntNumber = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    // If head is empty, create new list
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = node;
        last = node;
        node->previous = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        last -> next = node;
        node -> previous = last;
        last = node;
    }
}

// output the list
void outputList() {

    // start at first node in list
    struct Integers* ptr = head;

    // output the contents of the list
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", ptr->nIntNumber);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

In VS for Windows you need to set `Compile as C` option. Otherwise it will be compiled as C++ program.